# How to override the view signup class in Django-Allauth to redirect the user to an error page when the form is not valid?

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

Does anybody know how to override view signup class (when form is not valid need redirect to some page)?

```
class AccountSignupView(SignupView):
    template_name = 'example.html'
    form_class = UserSignupForm
    #if form field email is_valid its ok
    #else:
    #redirect('error-email.html')
```